# Have non-regular language classes of infinite words been studied?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, reference-request, context-sensitive

For regular languages we have $\omega$-regular languages which extend them to infinite words.

Are there such extensions for CFG's, CSG's and recursively enumerable languages?

Comment: This paper compares a number of formalisms: http://arxiv.org/abs/1308.4516 - is this what you are looking for? Note in particular that in this setting, it makes a difference whether you use grammars or automata to define your languages.

Comment: What's wrong with just using the respective automata models with Büchi's acceptance criterion?

Comment: Nothing, really. I just figured that since the question was explicitly about grammars, the arxiv paper might be interesting.

Comment: @KlausDraeger My comment was aimed towards nikhil_vyas, otherwise I'd have @-pinged you. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have the following MSO characterization of regular [nested word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_word) languages:

> Regular languages over nested words are exactly the set of languages described by Monadic second-order logic with two unary predicates call and return, linear successor and the matching relation ↝.

The recommended reference on [Nested Words and Visibly Pushdown Languages](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~alur/nw.html) treats infinite words in section [8. Nested $\omega$-Words](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~alur/Jacm09.pdf), and shows that the MSO characterization carries over:

> **Theorem  8.4** (MSO characterization of $\omega$-languages).
>   A language $L$ of nested $\omega$-words over $\Sigma$ is regular iff there is an MSO sentence $\varphi$ over $\Sigma$ that defines $L$.

Because often deterministic CFGs are actually visibly pushdown languages, this covers a huge portion of the practically relevant CFGs. Moreover, this even provides a context where considering $\omega$-languages is practically relevant, as explained in the same section of the reference.